# Python library that supports setting oauth response_type

Tags: python, oauth, flask, oauth-2.0, oauth2client

The server I am working with does not support code as a response type. I attempted to use flask-oauth but it does not support setting a response type. I was wondering whether it was possible to configure flask-oauth to change it to token. I have tried doing it by setting:

```
request_token_params = {'response_type': 'token', 'scope':'read'}
```

But I get the error

```
prepare_grant_uri() got multiple values for keyword argument 'response_type'
```

If not, does anyone know a python library that supports oauth2 and setting the response type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using [requests-oauthlib](https://github.com/requests/requests-oauthlib) to get the functionality I was looking for. You can use the MobileApplicationClient from oauthlib and pass it to the Oauth2Session. Here's an example:

```
from oauthlib.oauth2 import MobileApplicationClient
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth2Session
mobile = MobileApplicationClient(client_id)
s = OAuth2Session(client=mobile)
```